# Checking username availability

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have created an check username availability  inside a createuserwizard. And i had added a progress indicator to the checking process and would show a spinner image (in gif format) and it was done by using java script.

if the system is in the midst of checking the username in database, it would display the spinner image and at the same time display a text "Checking availability..."

And the problem not is the spinner image do not appear when it was checking..

Here is code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      // Hook the InitializeRequest event.
      Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);

      function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
          // Change div's CSS class and text content.
          $get('UserAvailability').className = 'progress';
          $get('UserAvailability').innerHTML = 'Checking availability...';

      }
  </script>


  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                        <tr> 
                            <td class="style4">Username:</td>
                            <td> 

                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    ontextchanged="Username_Changed" Width="190" />



                                     <div runat="server" id="UserAvailability" style="background-position: left; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-left: -250px; padding-left: 22px; float:right;"></div>
                          </td> 

                        </tr> 

                        </ContentTemplate>
                      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
 protected void Username_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        TextBox UserNameTextBox = (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");

        if (Membership.GetUser(UserName.Text) != null)
        {
          UserAvailability.InnerText = "Username taken, sorry.";
          UserAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "taken");

        }
        else
        {
         UserAvailability.InnerText = "Username available!";
         UserAvailability.Attributes.Add("class", "available");

        }
    }
```

I have used a masterpage, I had tried putting the JS file inside masterpage, but the image still not appearing.

**EDIT**

```
    <style type="text/css">
       #UserAvailability 
{
  padding-left: 22px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.progress
{
  background-image: url(Images/spinner.gif);
}

.taken
{
  background-image: url(Images/taken.gif);
}

.available
{
  background-image: url(Images/available.gif);
}


        </style>
```

Comment: why Threading.Sleep ?? Do you think your code is too fast and should slow down ?

Comment: Well I can't see any markup for a 'spinner image'... Why are you sleeping your thread too? You could have a css class that adds a background image to a div for the spinner via `div.AddCssClass("processing");` and then remove it when the task returns

Comment: Yes, I did add that to my cs file.. Look above post, I had edited